# Getting error when deploying my Play2.2.5 Application on Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have been searching and trying the things suggested for hours now and I still can't seem to get my play2.2.5 application to work on Heroku.

I get the error "An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.If you are the application owner, check your logs for details." From the website when I try to run it.

Here is the text in my **Procfile.txt**

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/homeworkorganizer -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}
```

You will notice that it doesn't contain that ${JAVA_OPTS}
Before I took that out, it didn't work either. And most of the websites I have looked at have said to remove it.

And here is the error gotten from "heroku logs"

[Error can be found here](http://pastebin.com/wSiCvVsD)

**So the question is what do I need to do in order to get it to work properly?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Database 'default' needs evolution!` If you try to access it from the browser don't you see an error stating you need to apply db evolutions like [this](http://blog.lunatech.com/2013/08/29/evolutions.png)?

Comment: `Procfile` probably shouldn't have an extension

Comment: No I dont see that "Database default needs evolution" because I have it set to apply those automatically...

Comment: And @m-z I am trying that right now... I remember reading on the tutorial that it said something like create a regular text file called Procfile... which is why I created the .txt, but Im looking at others and sure enough it doesnt have the .txt extension.

Comment: @m-z You should make that an answer because I think that is probably the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Procfile` should have no extension, so `Procfile.txt` is being ignored by heroku. Which means that `-DapplyEvolutions.default=true` is being ignored and some default configuration is probably being used.

This is being hinted by this error:

```
2015-01-25T00:08:11.035238+00:00 app[web.1]: [←[33mwarn←[0m] play - Run with -DapplyEvolutions.default=true if you want to run them automatically (be careful)
2015-01-25T00:08:11.039189+00:00 app[web.1]: @6l1h6pdpo: Database 'default' needs evolution!
```